# Is it possible to compress alpha and RGB channels of PNG sequence separately with FFmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, png, alpha-channel

Suppose I have a sequence of 32-bit (RGBa) PNG files. Is it possible to compress the RGB channel with one codec and the alpha channel with another? For example, if I had the RGB and alpha as separate PNG files (24 and 8 bit, respectively), I would do something like this:

```
ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i 24_bit_rgb%04d.png -c:v libx264rgb -qp 0 -preset veryslow rgb.mp4`

ffmpeg -framerate 60 -i 8_bit_alpha%04d.png -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 alpha.mp4`
```

But I’m not sure how I’d do this since I **don’t** have separate RGB and alpha PNG files. Can this be done in FFmpeg?

Comment: While this might have an answer, what is the ultimate question here? To me, it reads a bit like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info) where you have a goal, have decided this is the solution and want us to provide validity to this solution, but the “solution” might not actually solve your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [alphaextract](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#alphaextract) or [extractplanes](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#extractplanes) filters.

```
ffmpeg -i %04d.png -filter_complex "alphaextract[alf]" -map "[alf]" -c:v libx265 -x265-params lossless=1 alpha.mp4 -map 0 -c:v libx264rgb -qp 0 -preset veryslow rgb.mp4
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you.